# How does google add the light blue colored vertical and horizontal bars (html/Css)

Tags: html, css

As shown in this screenshot:

[image: http://imgur.com/fgyjr.png]

I tried looking in the source code , but couldn't find it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the header, they use empty `div`s with the class `.gbh`, which provides the style `border-top: 1px solid #C9D7F1;`

#### Firebug's Parsing

```
<span id="ghead" style="visiblity:visible;">
    <div id="guser" width="100%">...</div>
    <div class=gbh style=left:0></div>
    <div class=gbh style=right:0></div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use firebug or other similar tool and it'll take you 15 seconds.

```
border-left:1px solid #D3E1F9;
```